# How to delete a file without extension on a FTP server?

Tags: file, ftp, delete-file

There is one file in my FTP folder I can't delete.

I tried to rename the file with Filezilla or to delete the folder but it fails.
And that file is still there  with an unlink() php function.

The file is called **Jul 29 14:10** (without extension).

Please someone have any idea?

Comment: What is the error you getting?

Comment: FTP Error: 550 Delete operation failed

Comment: can you ssh in the server as root?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you already know this, (3 years after asking the question), but you need to escape spaces when you type a filename into the command line. You'd type it in as Jul\ 29\ 14:10 (I think.) Or you could navigate to the directory that contains it and type Jul, then press tab. It'll autocomplete. If it doesn't, press tab again and it will show you options.